# email hosting for massive number of accounts

Tags: email-server

I'm looking for an affordable e-mail hosting provider to host 18,000 + email accounts. The use case is as follows:

My company manufactures a line of SCADA devices that are each set up with an e-mail account. These devices can accept commands from users via e-mail and generate a lot of outbound e-mail with attachments ranging from a few KB to a few MB each.

I do not need a large amount of storage space per each account, since the devices only need to look at incoming e-mails once to parse them for commands. Sent e-mail likewise does not need to be stored on the mail server.

Most of the sites I've found charge anywhere from $1 to $5 per month per account, meaning my company would have to pay anywhere from $18,000 to $90,000 per month for the service which is far beyond our budget. All of these seem to offer accounts with around 10 to 25 GB of storage each, which is far, far more than we actually need.

Does anyone know of any affordable e-mail hosting providers with low storage space for our use case? We would need the ability to automatically register these accounts as the devices are manufactu

Comment: Why email? Can you use a webservice instead? That way you would just host a server and it'll accept the commands and send them to the actual devices. Much easier than an email.

Comment: @Alejandro I agree that it's really weird that they're using e-mail for this. Unfortunately, I don't have any control over the product. That was a decision made by management many many years ago and they are more or less set in their ways. Unfortunately, I have to find a way to make this work.

Comment: Sorry, but asking for an e-mail hosting provider is off-topic here. We recommend software applications. Do you want some software to run on your own server?

Comment: I believe a virtual mailbox based solution would fit your use case better with your own hosting. There is some information [here](https://dannorth.net/2007/09/09/virtual-mailboxes-with-courier-imap-and-postfix/)  - this scenario mentioned in the blog should fit your use case The second case is “more” virtual – the user doesn’t even need to exist on the server with a regular login account. Postfix puts the mail into a special directory, and courier-imap presents that directory as the mailbox when the user “logs in” over IMAP. This is known as virtual mailbox domains.

Comment: @Davis Jebaraj  thanks for the info on virtual mailboxes. This looks promising. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a decent sysadmin who knows Linux? You should be able to use something like `postfix`+`dovecot`+`mysql` to create and manage virtual users/aliases/forwards and run it all on a $20/mo VPS from Linode.com or similar.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Rao and i am the Manager Sales and Support of VEBNEST. I can help you with that let me know what is your budget. I can do something for you as per that. We are in hosting business since 2006.Also let me know your device locations so that i can arrange services within your region. Thanks

And i know what exactly what you want because i have BS(EE) degree :) and i did many projects like that. So i can better assist you in your project.

Best Regards
Rao

Comment: Can you expand on how your website fulfills the requirements? Like what features does it have and how it helps the OP. Otherwise it looks too much like spam in its current form.

Comment: Ok here you go.

Comment: you need to give us domain name that will be hosting or having those email addresses. We will give you control panel access to the server to create multiple email addresses you with with secure passwords. Now after that you can access those email boxes with any email client, like outlook. We will also provide you webmail access to each inbox. You will also get incoming outgoing smtp and pop server details, user, pwd and ports to configure your devices. . All server end tasks, management of mail server, mail boxes will be done by us.

Comment: Your all mail boxes will have SPF, DKIM, rDNS settings done by us. You can use seperate domain for mail services or your current domain which has website too but you will have to change the MX records to get it worked. We will help you in detail and will setup everything for you correctly. If you have any further questions let me know. Thanks

Comment: your all devices will be able to send and recieve email messages through the server and mailboxes that we will provide you. Please note i hereby assume that devices already programmed for sending and recieving or sending only email messages and they have fields like smtp or mail server hostname, username, password and port for smtp or pop fields in settings of device.

Comment: I also hereby assume that all devices has public network/internet connectivity. If your network or devices has special ports for smtp or pop or imap no issue we can set or change the ports as per requirements. Some ISPs block port 25 for smtp in that case we can setup mail services on different port for you.

Comment: Welcome aboard, Rao. In future, it would be better to edit your answer to add those details, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

i can give you space 100MB with each email account hosted in USA or EU at cost 0.25$/month per email account. Let me know if you are interested skype me SKYPEID: hotsol1

Rao

Comment: sorry, that would still cost my company around $4,500 a month. Way beyond our budget. We're not looking to spend more than $150 a month on this.

Comment: in that price you can get unmanaged on which you may be able to host email boxes. But if you need managed service with support then you have to go for email hosting and that will cost you. 0.25$ per email per month is very cheap and affordable. 25 cent only for managed email account service. Plus the email accounts that we will setup for you will be on 1Gigbit network port so that when 18000+ accounts will be connecting you wont get delays etc...

Comment: if you cant pay then go and create multiple free gmail accounts and link each device with  that :) but gmail only allow 500 emails per day from each account thats the limitation.

Comment: well its looking like we're going to need to set up our own mail server. I can get a dedicated server at a local data center for around $110 per month and set up all necessarily email services there. we already have a domain and I can add the MX records once that's set up.  I was just hoping I could find a service that does this to avoid having to roll our own mail service from scratch but since this is a very unusual use case, its looking like we will have to roll our own

Comment: yes you can get dedicated server but when you will connect 18000+ devices that server will stuck.

Comment: you need a gaint email server / mail exchange server that what we do and charge per account fee. If its that easy all big organization do that. Why then they hire email hosting accounts.

Comment: i dont think all 18,000 of the devices are going to connect at the exact same time, and i think the datacenter's network should be able to handle it. i'm still getting usage statistics from our old email service so i will know exactly how much bandwidth and processing power we'll need

Comment: https://www.cloudservers.pk/dedicated-servers server in 100$ choose location USA will save your 10$ more

Answer (score 0):

Email is a very simple protocol, have you considered just hosting yourself?

A single PC with **postfix** loaded on it.

1. Obviously the initial cost of the PC will be more.
2. Monthly cost electricity, bandwidth, and put money aside for hardware failures.
3. 25yr from google domains if you need a separate domain.

If bandwidth become a problem you could research hosting it on Amazon, Google, or etc cloud virtual machine.